# Python file download returning zero size

Tags: python, selenium, download, urllib2

I am trying to make a script to automate file acquisition in Python using urllib2. I've authenticated via NTLM, and am trying download encrypted/compressed files from a page which generates a varying-string unicode download link. Portions of the script are redacted as this is for enterprise use, but the text all seems accurate. My script thus far:

```
def dlFiles(dlLink):

    print "-----------------------"
    counter = 0
    fileName = []

    for item in dlLink:
        try:
            url = "constructed download URL"
            f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
            m = re.search("filename\*=utf-8\'\'(.*)", str(f.info()['Content-Disposition']))
            fileName.append(m.groups()[0])
            print "Downloading " + str(fileName[counter])
            #print f.info()

            with open(os.path.basename(fileName[counter]), "wb") as local_file:
                local_file.write(f.read())

        except HTTPError, e:
            print "HTTP Error:", e.code, url

        except URLError, e:
            print "URL Error:", e.reason, url

        counter += 1

    return fileName
```

The header returned is:

```
Date: Thu, 17 Jul 2014 19:09:45 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=utf-8''redacted.zip
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/x-download
X-Proxy-Host: redacted
```

As you can see, the content-length is listed as 0. I get the same header results when downloading via Chrome (a 0 content-length header) which results in no files being downloaded (just appropriately-named, empty files saved to the disk). Thinking that it could be a redirect issue, I tried using the requests library but got the same result.

Could it have something to do with the proxy host? Would it be more feasible to process any sort of redirect that may be happening via Selenium? All tips are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Selenium won't be of any help if you can't download it with Chrome. This seems like a server problem, not a problem with your code.

Comment: I am able to download the file with chrome, but the header in chrome also shows a 0 content-length. The file gets pushed with the filename received in the header, but the traffic recorded from the page is 0kB  in the chrome developer tool.

Comment: An empty file isn't of much use. This sounds like a server problem to me.